# Can I pass constraints to actions in deep q learning python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, agent, dqn

Currently I am using RL agent DQN to predict action and update the action value function. But if I have a constraint to run a particular action for n times, can I have a constraint in DQN specified for the agent to take action? If yes, How can I possibly do it (using TF)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the action for n steps. There are wrappers like [SuperSuit](https://github.com/PettingZoo-Team/SuperSuit) if you're using a gym environment. SuperSuit provides the `sticky_actions_v0` or `frame_skip_v0` for this.